# A-Frame – Check which 360°-Image is active and display additional image

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm just playing around with the 360° image gallery:
https://aframe.io/examples/showcase/360-image-gallery/

How do I check which 360° image is currently active and display additional images?

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what image is currently active by using this line of code:

```
document.querySelector("#image-360").getAttribute("material").src
```

This grabs the  with id = "image-360", so we can check what kind of image is being used. The attribute "material" is AFrame's object that is attached to  so that can change the source image, texture, color, opacity and a few more things.

Adding additional images would require you to create either  or  and apply a .setAttribute("src",  or );